# Converting LookupEntry to LookupMask in ProjectServer.Client Library

Tags: c#, csom, project-online

So I can't wrap my head around this, I tried different typecasting and trying to instantiate the LookupEntry to a LookupMask but no avail.

I need to get the MaskType from the LookupMask, that is connected to LookupEntry

[image: This is the first]

So the problem is I can't convert / typecast it with the built-in conversion (there are no otherway to convert it as far as I know and on documentation online)

You can see when I do debug in Visual Studio, the LookupMask/Mask is connected to LookupEntry.
[image: Debug Visual studio]

Any suggestion how I can access the LookupMask?

Edit:

I tried doing a foreach for mask, big problem. The count of mask is not equal to the count of entries. So if you have 6 entries, you can have 1 mask and all entries have the same mask. At the same time if you have 6 entries and 2 mask, 1 mask account for 5 entries and the other 1 is the other mask but you don't know which is which.

Comment: `foreach (var mask in lookupValue.Masks)`

Comment: Yeah I think that's the only solution I can see, a double foreach with Entries and Mask, it is weird they are 1:1 yet they are split and have no access to each other. I'm just wondering how my Visual Studio knows the LookupMask even though I can't typecast it.